# Using tikz/pgfplots axis grid coordinate in latest version

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to add annotations with nodes to a `pgfplots` plot using the coordinates of the `axis`' grid which here is more convenient than using absolute coordinates. I wanted to add an arrow to point out the Gaussian's width on the following plot

[image]

I managed to do it with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    grid = both,
]
\addplot
[
    samples = 100,
    color = blue!80,
    thick,
] {exp(-0.5*((x/2)^6)};
\draw [thick, <->] (-2, 0.6) -- (2, 0.6);
\draw (0, 0.65) node [above] {critical diameter};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

but if I am not running `pgfplots` in backward compatibility (i.e. if `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` is removed from the latter code) it produces

[image]

I believe `pgfplots` do not use the grid coordinates by default anymore in newer versions and I would like to learn how to produces the same result as with the backward compatibility using grid coordinates with the latest version of `pgfplots`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the comments in the code for an explanation and the solution.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
    ]
        \addplot[
            samples = 100,
            color = blue!80,
            thick,
        ] {exp(-0.5*(x/2)^6)};

        % by default up to `compat=1.10` the Tikz coordinate system is used
        % starting with `compat=1.11` the `axis` coordinate system is used
        \draw [thick, <->] (-2, 0.6) -- (2, 0.6)
            node [midway,above,red] {critical diameter}
        ;
        % to be sure that the `axis` coordinates are used,
        % give them the prefix `axis cs:`
        \draw [thick, <->] (axis cs:-2, 0.6) -- (axis cs:2, 0.6)
            node [midway,above,green] {critical diameter}
        ;

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Maybe you want to add `clip mode=individual`? Or move the nodes out of the `axis` environment? (+1 for the explanations.)

Comment: What adding `clip mode=individual` would do?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Stephan!

Comment: @Loïc It will prevent the red node "critical diameter" from being clipped.

Comment: Indeed, it's better with `clip mode = individual` as an option of the `axis` environment. And why moving out the nodes of the `axis` environment would be better?

Comment: @Loïc In this example it does not matter, but it does e.g. when you have plot marks, you may get overshooting ones when you dial `clip mode=individual`.  Anyway, as you do not seem to want the red text, in this example the discussion is not too relevant.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, have you ever seen an answer of mine *without* explanations? I do this because then ordinary people, that is people who are not PGFPlots experts, have an idea not only *what* is done but often also *why* this *needs* to be done.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, your last comment is the reason I didn't add `clip mode=individual` :) I would have is that would be directly relevant to the answer and then I would also have explained why this is beneficial to `clip=false` (for these use-cases). (Actually I know that I sometime *did* this already in another answer.)

Comment: @StefanPinnow I also like to explain "why" but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp4dpeJVDxs reminds us that this is a nontrivial task: you never know what the other side knows. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, *g, totally agree :) We just try to do our best and give a trade-off. Luckily people can write comments to the answers and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid]
\addplot
[
    samples = 100,
    color = blue!80,
    thick,
] {exp(-0.5*((x/2)^6)};
\draw [thick, <->] (axis cs: -2, 0.6) -- node[above,font=\footnotesize] {critical diameter} (axis cs: 2, 0.6);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer!